# format and renderer not working together in etxjs6

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have written a field like

```
 Ext.define('Abc.view.component.grid.Mes', {
     extend: "Ext.grid.column.Number",
     text: 'Mes',
     dataIndex: 'Mes',
     xtype: 'Mes',
     format:'0',
     renderer: function (value) {
         return (value ? (value*100 ) + '%' : '');
     }
 });
```

From backend i get value like 0.776. So i want to show value in grid like 78% i.e. 0.776 * 100 and then rounded off value. The above function is not working. How should i write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` property is used by the default renderer. As you've supplied your own renderer, if you want to do formatting, do it there.